# How to make toothbrush Bristle animation

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

[image]Hi all, I am a student and a newbie in using blender. I just know the basic for the modelling and animate with time frame. I want to make an animation for brushing teeth but I don't know how to animate the bristle. I want to make the bristle to be soft and bending when contacting the surface of the Teeth and not penetrating into the teeth model. below i have attach the sample animation picture that i made but the bristle is not real as it penetrate into the teeth model. Can anyone help to teach me how to make the bristle soft and deform/bend when contacting the surface of the teeth? I really appreciate your help. Thank you everyone!

Comment: have you tried particle system? you can change stiffness and other values for realistic results . but i think some bones will do better and you dont need simulation for it( i mean bendy bones)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by mma78 in the comment try a ***Hair Particle System***.

[image: brushing the default cube]
<sup>Brushing the default cube</sup>

1. Make an emitter plane:

   - Copy a few faces of the lower side of the toothbrush head where the brushes sit. In *Edit mode*, duplicate <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or RMB to leave it where it is, and separate selection with <kbd>P</kbd>)
   - In *Object mode*, rename the plane, and parent it to the toothbrush (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Parent must be selected last = highlighted light orange.
2. Add a *Hair Particle System* to the bristle plane

   - `150` particles
   - 3, 5, or `8` segments (I used 8. Test it, less can make the bristle stiffer)
3. In *Field Weights* turn off gravity:

   - *Gravity*: `0.000`  (we do not want to bend the bristles to the ground)
4. Adjust these values for render and the shape/appearance of the bristles:

   - *Render*:

     - `[_]` *Show Emitter* (disabled, we don't want to render it)
     - *Path* → *Steps*: `5`
   - *Viewport Display*:

     - *Strand Steps*: `5`
   - *Children*: `Simple`

     - *Radius*: `0.02m` (**adjust this** to your toothbrush size! Value here is for the 2m default cube!)
     - *Roundness*: `1.000`
   - *Clumping*:

     - `[X]` *Use Clump Curve*
     - (`edit a curve`. Make it round in the top right corner. This makes the bristles heads round)
   - *Hair Shape:*

     - *Strand Shape*: `-0.850`    (for rounded bristles)
     - *Diamenter Root*:  `0.3m`    (**adjust this** to your toothbrush size!)
5. enable `[X]` *Hair Dynamics*. Run/bake the simulation and play with the *Hair Dynamics* values:

   - *Collision*

     - *Distance*: `5cm` (**adjust this** to your toothbrush size!)
   - *Pin Goal Strength*: `10`
   - *Structure*:

     - *Vertex Mass*: `0.3 kg` (default, higher values make the bristles inert)
     - *Stiffness*: `30` (higher values result in less bending)
     - *Damping*: `0.300` (default, increase if the bristles swing too much)

Happy teeth brushing!

Comment: thanks for the reference, but what about the settings for collision sir?