# Finger Nail and Brush Animation

Tags: animation

I am particularly interested in making a short animationin blender which consists of a detailed view of a finger nail, finger tissue, nail brush, layer of nail polisher, etc. the image shows exactly what I am aiming to create.

I would be very grateful if you could direct me in finding a source of skills and material or perhaps share the steps you would take in approach this particular scenario. I am also willing to pay for explanation and guidance.[image]

Comment: What is the green stuff there? Wait, I don't want to know. For a brush animation, you can use hair particles [How to make toothbrush Bristle animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/210108/107598). If you want to keep the point of view in cross-section view, you could model a nail and fake the layers with a displacement modifier/bump map. For the layer of nail polisher you can use simple *Shape Keys*... (or *Dynamic Paint*?).