# Colliding hair system with canvas for dynamic paint

Tags: hair, collision, dynamic-paint

I am getting decent with the UI, but still a blender noob.

Trying to make a working paintbrush for an animation. I want the hair to collide properly with the canvas and look like brush hair.
[image: frame 0]
And no amount of experimentation has gotten me there. I've messed a ton of different ratios of

- stiffness
- pin goal
- hair path segments
- substeps

but still getting a stiff weird unreactive brush. My collisions with the canvas itself have seemed off, often the brush hairs pass right through the canvas, and collision modifiers have only sort of fixed that. [image]

[image: profile view]

I figured out how to attach an object to the end of the hairs, in order to make dynamic paint work with the hair particles. At least I sort of did- proximity to the canvas of the end of the hair has been a problem because of the collision inaccuracies. As you can see I have proximity paint set way too high(.4) in order for the image sequence to show any paint at all.
[image]

I sometimes get kinks from the collision, at the base of the hair.

You can see the hairs pass through the surface of the canvas -
inner thickness=0.001
outer thickness=0.1
[image: this is as close as I've ever gotten the collision to exact]

Possibly due to a conflict between particle weight and the hair dynamics?
[image: particle weight and comb]

This is the closest I've gotten on the realism front-
Segments=12
.44m length
30 quality steps
Pin Goal Strenth=7.0
stiffness=1.5
As you can see the kink is still an issue, and I don't seem to get any lateral splay of the hairs. Is this a pin goal issue?
[image]

The truth is I don't know what a generic setting for any of these parameters might be. Perhaps I'm way to high on pin goal or stiffness? Or low? It's seemed like any lower than this would cause air/gravity/inertia to cause the hair to hang in the air or float on it. I tried removing air forces, but didn't seem to make a difference, so perhaps that's an inertial effect? unclear. Or my collision thickness is too small for what I want?

So I don't really have a starting point, and don't know what's breaking the animation. If anybody could help me out with getting the hair dynamics anywhere close to functional that'd be amazing. I'd be happy to start the system from scratch if someone wanted to share any project settings from similar projects.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you increased the *Path Steps* and *Strand Steps*? This will make the bristles bend smoother. I made a while ago a teeth brush from the default cube, it might be helpful? Have a look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210108/how-to-make-toothbrush-bristle-animation

Comment: Path steps no? Not sure what you're referring to. I have messed with the strand steps at the top of the hair particle settings (2.90).  I don't think I ever tried anything higher than 20 or so, but that seemed excessive. 

Viewport rendering for the hair in the photos I sent is set to 3, so they look janky there, the render is better, much smoother, but still has the kink in it. 

The link you gave is great though, exactly what I was looking for. And I can see a couple places I'm way off of the specs you gave.  Thanks so much. I will report with my results.